# JsViews / JsRender table rendering with GroupBy an attribute/property

Tags: javascript, jsrender, jsviews

I am using JsViews to design a template.
However I wonder if we can groupBy an attribute based on its string value?

JSON sample:

```
"ItemDetails": [
    {
        "Amount": 2000,
        "Name": "Horror Book",
    },
    {
        "Amount": 3500,
        "Name": "Horror Book",
    },
    {
        "Amount": 1000,
        "Name": "Children Book",
    },
],
```

Current code is outlining each item even if it has the same name.

```
{{for ItemDetails}}
{{if Amount}}
            <row>
                <col>{{>Name}}</col>
                <col>{{>Amount}}</col>
            </row>
{{/if}}
{{/for}}
```

I want it to have result like this:

Horror Book 5500

Children Book 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsRender/JsViews [{{for}}](https://www.jsviews.com/#fortag) and [{{props}}](https://www.jsviews.com/#propstag) tags have built-in support for sorting, filtering etc, but don't have a built-in *groupBy* feature. But you can fairly easily create one, following similar techniques to the [*grid with ~total()*](https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/tags/extend-for@for) sample.

Here is an approach using helper functions:

```
<table><tbody>
  {{for ItemDetails sort="Name"}}
    {{if ~groupBy("Name", "Amount")}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{>Name}}</td>
        <td>{{>~total()}}</td>
      </tr>
    {{/if}}
  {{/for}}
</tbody></table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/nx3atd1q/

And here is an alternative version using the filter feature on *{{for}}*:

```
<table><tbody>
  {{for ItemDetails sort="Name" filter=~groupBy groupTotal="Amount"}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{>Name}}</td>
      <td>{{:~total()}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/for}}
</tbody></table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/o4pt3brq/

Comment: thank you. Although can you explain what is the difference between `this.data` and `this.parent.data` ?

Comment: With `~groupBy("Name", "Amount")`, the `this` pointer  is the view.
See https://www.jsviews.com/#viewobject@access.

Here, we are in a `{{for}}` loop, so `this` is an "Item view", and `this.data` is the item.
`this.parent` is the parent view (here, an "Array view"), and `this.parent.data` is the array of items.

See https://www.jsviews.com/#views, to understand view hierarchy.